# Adding a submenu

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem

So I tried to look at the Java docs for help for this but got confused pretty quickly. I am trying to add a submenu to the menu item 'Edit' which will have submenus Copy and Paste, and I'm note sure how to do it. I have a submenu variable created, do I use that? Please help, thank you. Code is below.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

public class MyJFrame extends JFrame
{
JMenuBar menubar;
JMenu menu, submenu;
JMenuItem mi;

public MyJFrame(String title)
{
    super(title);
    menubar = new JMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(menubar);
    buildMenu();
}

void buildMenu()
{
menu = new JMenu("File");

           mi = new JMenuItem("New");
           menu.add(mi);
           menubar.add(menu);

           mi = new JMenuItem("List Files");
           menu.add(mi);
           menubar.add(menu);
           menu.addSeparator();

           mi = new JMenuItem("Save As");
           menu.add(mi);
           menubar.add(menu);
           menu.addSeparator();

           mi = new JMenuItem("Close");
           menu.add(mi);
           menubar.add(menu);

    menu = new JMenu("Tools");

           mi = new JMenuItem("Sort");
           menu.add(mi);
           menubar.add(menu);

           mi = new JMenuItem("Search");
           menu.add(mi);
           menubar.add(menu);

           mi = new JMenuItem("Edit");
           menu.add(mi);
           menubar.add(menu);
           mi = new JMenuItem("Copy");
           menu.add(mi);
           menubar.add(menu);
           mi = new JMenuItem("Paste");
           menu.add(mi);
           menubar.add(menu);
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

create a Menu instead of a MenuItem for Edit, and add MenuItems Copy and Paste. Then Add edit menu to Tools Menu .

```
   menu = new JMenu("Tools");

       mi = new JMenuItem("Sort");
       menu.add(mi);
       mi = new JMenuItem("Search");
       menu.add(mi);
      JMenu med = new JMenu("Edit");
        mi = new JMenuItem("Copy");
       med.add(mi);
        mi = new JMenuItem("Paste");
       med.add(mi);
       menu.add(med);
     menubar.add(menu);
```

Note: I have edited the last part of your code. Just replace the code from tools menu to this and try this. If it gets error, tell me.

Comment: Why do you add `menu` to `menubar` three times? You should remove that.

Comment: Done, actually i had just copied and edited the last past of his code. So it got left...

Comment: Good. Mistakes can happen ;) Though I'm not your bro, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example of how you can do it:

```
JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

// Edit Menu
JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");    
menuBar.add(editMenu);

// Edit -> Copy
JMenuItem copyMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Copy");
editMenu.add(copyMenuItem);

// Edit -> Paste
JMenuItem pasteMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Paste");
editMenu.add(pasteMenuItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplified excerpt from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html

[Result image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/figures/uiswing/components/MenuLookDemo.png)

```
menu.addSeparator();
submenu = new JMenu("A submenu"); 

menuItem = new JMenuItem("An item in the submenu");
submenu.add(menuItem);

menuItem = new JMenuItem("Another item");
submenu.add(menuItem);
menu.add(submenu); // you add the submenu to your existing menu
```